Change font style figure number
I'm sorry if this question sounds a bit naive, I'm quite new to LateX. I'm using \autoref to cross-reference figures. I've used this command to personalize the appearance of it:
\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{\textsf{Fig.\negthinspace}}

So it appears like "Fig. X.X"
My problem is that the "Fig. " part appears in sans serif font but not the following number i.e. "X.X" What can I do to make the figure number appear in "sans serif" font as well ?

welcome! do you want cross-refs to use sans, too, or only in the label? can you provide code for a minimal example?

If you want it to change everwehre, modify \thefigure.
